# how to override vue cli-service entry settings

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli-3

I'm trying to integrate a vue project that I built with the vue cli into an existing .net app.  I'm very new to vue, so I'm trying to follow guides and such, but am left with lots of questions.

While trying to compile this, I found that the vue cli-service node module has the following for setting the main.js file located in it's base.js file.

```
webpackConfig
  .mode('development')
  .context(api.service.context)
  .entry('app')
    .add('./src/main.js')
    .end()
  .output
    .path(api.resolve(options.outputDir))
    .filename(isLegacyBundle ? '[name]-legacy.js' : '[name].js')
    .publicPath(options.publicPath)
```

I need to override this since my .net app doesn't have a src directory and the usage of this vue app won't follow that path structure.  I'm not seeing a way to do it in my vue.config.js file.  I would expect that if I can override it, that would be the spot.

I could overwrite the base.js file where this exists, but when a co-worker runs npm install, they would get the default value rather than what I have.  The only option I see there is checking in all the node modules to git which we really don't want to do.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in a similar situation, I found what worked for me.  It's not the ideal solution due to the fact that it forces you to build into a js folder.  That resulted in the file being put in Scripts\build\vue\js.  Would be nice to be able to just dump it in the vue folder, but at least this works.  Code below.

vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath : "/",
  outputDir: "Scripts/build/vue", //where to put the files

  // Modify Webpack config
  // https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#chainwebpack
  chainWebpack: config => {
    // Not naming bundle 'app'
    config.entryPoints.delete('app'); //removes what base.js added
  },

  // Overriding webpack config
  configureWebpack: {
    // Naming bundle 'bundleName'
    entry: {
      quote: './Scripts/Quote/index.js' //where to get the main vue app js file
    },
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: false
    }
  },
  filenameHashing: false,
  pages: {
    quoteApp: { //by using pages, it allowed me to name the output file quoteApp.js
      entry: './Scripts/Quote/index.js',
      filename: 'index.html'
    }
  }
}
```